# Load an image (background-image CSS) dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to convert the background-image (css) into an object to change it's value but I couldn't find a solution.
At the moment there are 2 images in the script the first one is a circle loader script and the second one is a script that based of the value of the range it shows or hides part of the picture.
What i'm trying to do is to make load the picture inside the circle loader script.
For instance if the circle loader is 30/100 it should show only display 30% of the picture inside the circle vertically.

Here's the code:

Live version:

```js
var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
  color: '#aaa',
  // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
  // prevent clipping
  strokeWidth: 4,
  trailWidth: 1,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  text: {
    autoStyleContainer: false
  },
  from: { color: '#aaa', width: 1 },
  to: { color: '#333', width: 4 },
  // Set default step function for all animate calls
  step: function(state, circle) {
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

    var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
    if (value === 0) {
      circle.setText('');
    } else {
      circle.setText(value);
    }

  }
});
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0




var sldH = document.getElementById('slider-h');
var sldV = document.getElementById('slider-v');
var img = document.getElementById("image");

// attach change handlers to the sliders
sldH.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
sldV.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);

function changeHandler(e) {
    
    var isHorizontal = e.srcElement.id == 'slider-h';
        
    // get the sliders values
    var valH = sldH.value;
    var valV = sldV.value;

    // calculate the percentage to pass an absolute length value 
    // to the clip property and determine the static value
    var leftVal = calcPerc(img.width, valH);
    var topVal = -1 * calcPerc(img.height, valV);
    var clipVal = getClipVal(topVal, leftVal);

    // set the images' right offset clip accordingly
    img.style.clip = clipVal;
}

function calcPerc(range, val) {
    return range / 100 * val;
}

function getClipVal(top, left) {
    return 'rect(' + top + 'px, auto, auto, ' + left + 'px)';
}
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  top: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/bitcoin/bitcoin_PNG47.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.btc{
  background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/bitcoin/bitcoin_PNG47.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#slider-h,
#slider-v,
#image,
#underlay {
    /* absolute positioning is mandatory for clipped elements (#image) */
    position: absolute;
}
#slider-h,
#image,
#underlay {
    width: 192px;
    left: 100px;
}
#slider-h {
    top: 50px;
    left: 350px;
}
#slider-v {
    top: 192px;
    left: 200px;;
    width: 207px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
#image,
#underlay {
    top: 100px;
    left: 350px;
    height: 207px;
}
#image {
    /* initial clip state */
}
#underlay {
    /*background-color: #4C76A5;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600,800,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="container" >
</div>

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="slider-h" value="0" />
<input type="range" min="-100" max="0" id="slider-v" value="0" />
<div id="underlay"></div>
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/bitcoin/bitcoin_PNG47.png" id="image" />
```

I hope somebody can help! Thanks